# How to access Array of one child module from Parent module without using any library?

Tags: javascript

I am using vanilla js to create task manager. I want to access returned array of imported module.

```
import * as createEle from './createEle.js';
const main = document.getElementById('main');
const add_task = document.getElementById('addTask');
const inProgress = [];

add_task.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    addTask();
});

function addTask(){
     const taskArray=[inputTask, node, addButton]=createEle.createNewElements();
     console.log(taskArray);
}
```

```
This is exported module--

export function createNewElements(){
    const allTask = [];
    const inputTask = document.createElement("form");
    const node = document.createElement("input");
    const addButton = document.createElement("button");
    let key = Date.now();
    main.appendChild(inputTask);
    inputTask.appendChild(node);
    inputTask.appendChild(addButton);
    addButton.innerText = "Add Your Task";
    inputTask.setAttribute("class", "inputArea");
    node.setAttribute("key", key);
    node.setAttribute("placeholder", "Put Your Task Here");
    allTask.push(inputTask,node, addButton);

    return allTask;
}
```

I want to access the returned array allTask. But I'm getting error.

Comment: Can you please update your post with the error message you are getting?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: inputTask is not defined
    at addTask (index.js:11:23)
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (index.js:7:5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You Should know that there are :

1. **Named import:**

```js
import { export1, export2 } from "module-name";
```

2. **Default import**:

```js
import defaultExport from "module-name";
```

3. **Namespace import:**

```js
 import * as name from "module-name";
```

4. **Side effect import:**

```js
 import "module-name";
```

You used the `default import`:

```js
import myDefault, * as myModule from "/modules/my-module.js";
```

While your export is a `Named export`

```js
export function createELement(){...}
```

*There
's a contreversation here!*

To solve your issue you have two solutions:

1. `Named import` :

```js
import {createNewElements} from "./CreateEle" // Your case
```

2. `Default export` :

```js
export default function createNewElements { //code here }

// In your imported module ex: index.js

import createNewElements from "./createEle"
```

This is quick-example :

1. `create.js`:

```js
export default function createNewElements() {
  const allTask = [1, 2, 3];
  return allTask;
}
```

2. `index.js`

```js
import createNewElements from './create.js';
const taskArray = createNewElements()
function logTask() {
  console.log(taskArray);
}
logTask();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `import {createNewElements} as allTasks from './createEle.js';`

Comment: No, It's not working.

Comment: in the exported module, try defining the function like normal then at the end of the script put `module.exports.createNewElements = createNewElements`

Comment: No, It's not working....